# Undefine reference error for static function

Tags: c++

I have below code and I am getting undefined reference to `StInit::instance()'

File StInit.h

```
class StInit
{
public:
static StInit* instance();
};
```

File StInit.cc

```
#include "StInit.h"

StInit*
StInit::instance()
{
    static StInit *myPtr = NULL;
    ......
    ......
    return myPtr;
}
```

File nm.cc

```
#include "StInit.h"
StInit* stor_init = StInit::instance();
```

I don't know why I am getting this error. How to resolve this error?

Comment: what are your build command(s)?

Comment: I am using tup based file system. So "tup upd" is my build command

Comment: What platform are you building on? Could you perhaps try building with something else and reproducing the problem? Can you use visual studio express for example?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not including the 2nd file `StInit.cc` into the binary, hence the linker error. I am not familiar with tup, but looking at the manual it seems you need to include both the files in the tup file.

Look at the last example in this documentation: http://gittup.org/tup/ex_a_first_tupfile.html, just copying it as is should get you going.

So change the `Tupfile` to:

```
: foreach *.c |> gcc -Wall -c %f -o %o |> %B.o
: *.o |> gcc %f -o %o |> hello
```

And `hello` should have both the files compiled and linked in.

Comment: Nope. It's already in a good shape.Same as you mention.